# How can I exclude some of severity of log levels on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I want to reduce my GCP billing costs, especially cloud logging cost, i have reduce retention period of logs, i have delete unnecessary logs on my source code, but i want to exclude some severities of log level like "debug, warning, etc.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to decrease a number of logs collected from your VM's you can reconfigure the [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/default-logs) so it will produce less logs - you have to change [log level](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging#by-config-file) to achieve this.

You can find your `fluentd` config file usually under `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf` (for RPM, Deb or DMG based systems). In other cases consult the [config file location docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#config-file-location).

You can do this from the command line:

> The -q option sets the verbosity to warn while the -qq option sets the verbosity to error:

```
$ fluentd -q  ... # warn log level
$ fluentd -qq ... # error log level
```

Also have a look at this documentation [here](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging#by-config-file) regarding what kind of logs are being collected by default so you can have a point of reference for decreasing them.